# Simple slider does not change src

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made i very simple slider which has worked past hours but it doesn't make anything despite i change nothing. I cannot find error. It has worked past hours ago and i don't know wat is wrong now.
Demo: [buhehe.de/allgemeinen/nackte-frauen/](http://buhehe.de/allgemeinen/nackte-frauen/)
I have two slider and each has its JS which i put in Head inline withoud external files:

JS:

```js
var imageCount = 1;
var total = 9;

function photo(x) {
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    imageCount = imageCount + x;
    if(imageCount > total){imageCount = 1;}
    if(imageCount < 1){imageCount = total;} 
    image.src = "/wp-content/uploads/2018/img/"+ imageCount +".jpg";
    clearInterval(time);                                 
    time =  window.setInterval(function photoA() {       
        var image = document.getElementById('image');
        imageCount = imageCount + 1;
        if(imageCount > total){imageCount = 1;}
        if(imageCount < 1){imageCount = total;} 
        image.src = "/wp-content/uploads/2018/img/"+ imageCount +".jpg";
    },10);
}
var iCount = 1;
var totl = 8;
function phot(x) {
    var images = document.getElementById('images');
    iCount = iCount + x;
    if(iCount > totl){iCount = 1;}
    if(iCount < 1){iCount = totl;}  
    images.src = "/wp-content/uploads/2018/img/g/"+ iCount +".png";
    clearInterval(time);                                 
    time =  window.setInterval(function photoA() {       
        var images = document.getElementById('images');
        iCount = iCount + 1;
        if(iCount > totl){iCount = 1;}
        if(iCount < 1){iCount = total;} 
        images.src = "/wp-content/uploads/2018/img/g/"+ iCount +".png";
    },10);
}
```

css:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 665px) {
     #image, #images{
         width: 400px !important;
         height:300px !important;
    }
     #slider, .slddl {
         width: 400px !important;
         height:300px !important;
    }
    .left,.right {
        width:35px !important;
        height:35px !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #image, #images{
        width: 300px !important;
        height:200px !important;
    }

    #slider, .slddl  {
        width: 300px !important;
        height:200px !important;
    }
}
.slddl {
    height: 400px !important;
    text-align: center  !important;
}
#slider {
    width: 400px;
    max-width:600px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:4px;
}
#image {
    width: 400px;
    height: 450px;
}
#images {
    width: auto !important;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block  !important;
}
#qttq {
    width: 100 !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}
.left {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left:5px;
    opacity:1;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.right {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right:5px;
    opacity:1;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.right:hover ,  .left:hover {
    opacity:0.8; cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), since most of your code probably has nothing to do with the actual problem

Comment: Can u check my website? Yes nothing i wrong but it doesn t change src...

Comment: Sorry, that page cannot be found. This is what i am getting when I am visiting your page. Could you provide a JSFiddle or URL?

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't change source?

Comment: This is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/whcfxfwr/1/

Comment: I mean it doesnt show next image